# É possível implementar métodos a null ou undefined?

Tags: javascript

Se eu quisesse implementar uma verificação de variável sempre que eu fosse utilizar o método `.indexOf()` do javascript isso seria possível?

Por exemplo usando `a.indexOf(b);` é possivel detectar quando o `a` é `null` ou `undefined` e alterar o método para retornar `-1`?

Comment: Podes explicar melhor como queres usar? queres modificar o `indexOf()`? dá um exemplo, pf

Comment: Sim. Quero modificá-lo. Para sempre que for usar ele já tratar se é nulo ou undefined e seguir o codigo sem dar erro.

Comment: Por exemplo `a.indexOf(b);` queres tratar se o `a` f^r `null` ou o `b` fôr `null` ? e que resultado dar caso `b`seja `null`?  `-1`?

Comment: No caso somente tratar se "a" é null ou undefined. E o resultado seria -1 caso fosse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é possível estender o `null` ou uma variavel que seja `undefined`. Ou seja se tiveres:

```
a.indexOf(b);
```

no caso de o `a` ser `null` ou `undefined` isso vai dar erro.

Soluções?!

Uma variante é usares `try{}catch(e){}` dessa maneira crias uma zona segura onde podes correr código sem que pare a execução por causa de erros.

```
var result;
try{
    result = a.indexOf(b);
} catch(){
    result = -1;
}
```

Outra opção é criares uma função para fazer isso.

```
function indexOf(str, el){
    if (!str && str != 0) return -1;
    return str.indexOf(el);
}
var result = indexOf(a, b);
```